# z-index with backgourd image & transparencey

Tags: html, z-index

I am trying to create a semi transparent div & write text on top of that.

So I have create a parent tag with position relative.
Having one child span with transparency set `.body-content-background`
and another child that has all the text content `menu-bar`

I have set the `z-index` of parent div as `-999`
background child div as `-9` 
and text div child as `1`

But still the `<a>` links in text div are not clickable.. ( or the white semi transparent div) doesn't appear)

http://jsfiddle.net/GauravMShah/MHhNG/

can someone tell me where I am wrong ?

Comment: 'Ingridients' is spelled 'Ingredients'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were aiming for?
http://jsfiddle.net/MHhNG/1/

I've changed your z-index values around, so the background is 0, transparent div is 1 and links are 2 (I had to add this in and give them position: relative).

You probably want to change them again to have more spaced out values incase you need to fit other things inbetween them (eg 10, 20, 30).

Comment: Yeah I fiugred out z-index but why position relative ?

Comment: You need it to make the z-index work - only elements with position: absolute, fixed or relative can have a z-index.

Comment: Then why not give body-background as -999 & white-bg as -10 and rest will should fall into place isn't it ?

Comment: If you can make it work like that then do it that way. Personally I find it a lot easier to work with positive z-index values instead of negative ones because of the way they inherit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this thing simply with opacity and filter on the parent div.
ie:

```
#main {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;   
    background-color: #000;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=2,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.60);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=2,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.60)";  zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: this would make the text within that div also semi-transparent